# Permission for logged in user steps

Tags: django, permissions

I am creating an app with recipes. Now i want to make that a logged in user can add recipes by himself. I know that i have to create some permission for this user, but i do not know how. I do not need any code i am just wondering if you can give me some direction what must be done. Do i have to add some user to my model and create permission.py?

My model:

```
from django.db import models


class Ingredient(models.Model):

  ingredient_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.ingredient_name


class Recipe(models.Model):

  recipe_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  preparation = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
  ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient)


  def __str__(self):
    return self.recipe_name
```

admin:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Recipe
from .models import Ingredient


admin.site.register(Recipe)
admin.site.register(Ingredient)
```

Comment: you can add if not request.user.is_authenticated:
  raise Http404 in your create view

Comment: Hi,  now adding recipes is possible only in admin panel, how can i take it to normal view?

Comment: you have to create seperate view, urls and templates for that

Comment: but i have already created it in models.py but it is shown only i admin panel hmm.

Comment: I will try to find some tutorial. But thanks for some tips. :)

Comment: okay, a code example is shown in answer section for reference. For tutorial this link is useful https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using a function based view, can add these checks while creating a recipe

```
def recipe_create(request):
    if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise Http404
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        raise Http404

    form = RecipeForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, "recipe_form.html", context)
```

Comment: Hi, i do not have something like recipe_form.html. I can add recipes as admin and i just want that logged in user can do the same on my website (so not in admin panel) after he is logged in lui93.pythonanywhere.com

Comment: if you allow users to admin panel, they can alter what ever they want, so it is not advisable. You have to create form also

Comment: I thought maybe i could give them permission to only add recipe but not to the other functions and i was wondering if this is possible and if this is maybe the fastest way to do it.